# EF Core ASP.Net Core edit migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

If I need to change the database migration, should I add it to the existing migration in the column table or do I need to change the data in the designer? It is important to save the data and keep the startup migration ready.

[image]

Comment: [READ ME](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In practice i recomment you not touch the migration,instead run the command `Remove-Migration`, edit the Configuration of the entities and run the command `Add-Migration <migration-name>`.

Or if the app is in development phase simpply use the following steps:

1-remove the folder migration

2-in the nuggets terminal run `Drop-Database` command

3-run `Add-Migration <migration-name>`

4-run `Update-Database`

Then you will recreate the database with the modifications.